# cordova inAppBrowser "Before Exit" event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a cordova (android) app with window popout using window.open javascript that override with cordova inAppBrowser when device is ready refer to the code below:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

Then i want to set an event when user press phone back button or  press "x" button to close the popout a dialog will pop out and asked "Are you sure? Y/N" before closing window popout. The code look like this:

```
var newwindow;
newwindow = window.open('something', '_self ', 'location=no'); 
newwindow.addEventListener('exit', function(event){ Exit() });
 function Exit(){
              navigator.notification.confirm(
                'Are you sure?',  
                function(i){
                    if(i==2)
                     {
                      //exit the window popout
                     }
                },              
                'App Name',            
                'Cancel,Exit'          
              );
```

But it doesn't work as i wanted, the popout window closed then dialog is prompt to user...How can i show a dialog and decides whether to close popout window.

**Note: Sorry for bad grammar, i try my best to explain my problem.**

Comment: exit event is fired when the inAppBrowser is closed, so there is nothing you can do by then

Comment: So there is no way handle such event?

Comment: exit is just to know when it was closed, you can't prevent it without modifying the plugin native code.

Comment: I see, so is there any guide about this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no guide. From Android Studio you can open the `yourProject/platforms/android` folder and edit the `InAppBrowser.java` file. Maybe the plugin creation guide can be useful https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html

Comment: Or is there any alternatives ?  I just want a popup that runs a webpage (javascript) and able to handle "On exit" or "Before Exit" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fairly easy solution (android) for simple prompt like "Are you sure" "yes/no?" by editing the inappbrowser.dialog.java file. This solution is only prompting for confirmation before closing inappbrowser, which is suitable for my case.

Modify the java file `InAppBrowserDialog.java` in this location:

```
[your cordova project]/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/inappbrowser/
```

1. ADD REQUIRED IMPORTS:
   import android.content.DialogInterface;
2. MODIFY THE *onBackPressed()* FUNCTION

FROM:

```
public void onBackPressed () {
    if (this.inAppBrowser == null) {
        this.dismiss();
    } else {
        // better to go through the in inAppBrowser
        // because it does a clean up
        if (this.inAppBrowser.hardwareBack() && this.inAppBrowser.canGoBack()) {
            this.inAppBrowser.goBack();
        }  else {
            this.inAppBrowser.closeDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

TO:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Exit")
        .setMessage("You are about to exit, are you sure?")
        .setPositiveButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                if (inAppBrowser == null) {
                    dismiss();
                } 
                else {
                    // better to go through the in inAppBrowser
                    // because it does a clean up
                    if (inAppBrowser.hardwareBack() && inAppBrowser.canGoBack()) {
                        inAppBrowser.goBack();
                    }  else {
                        inAppBrowser.closeDialog();
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialogBuilder.show();
}
```

I basically just create an alert dialog on top of checking for inappbrowser when back button is pressed.

Comment: I don't have /android in my /platforms. Why is that? How should I generate that? Thanks.

Comment: Probably you do not have android platform in your cordova project. Open your terminal and "cd" your cordova project (with config.xml file) then type "cordova platform ls" it will list out all the platforms that your project have. You can refer to "Platform" section in [cordova cli guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/#add-platforms)